# Stuck with installing Ubuntu on Asus G733QS

Tags: system-installation

I'm getting stuck with installing Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (latest) on a brand new Asus (ROG Strix) G733QS. There are [successful installations with Debian 11 and Mint 20.3 on this hardware](https://linux-hardware.org/?view=computers&year=2021&type=Notebook&vendor=ASUSTek%20Computer&model=ROG%20Strix%20G733QS_G733QS). In my (Ubuntu) case, however, after booting from USB flash (FastBoot and SecureBoot are disabled), and selecting the (OEM) install option, I end up with both ROG and Ubuntu logos on screen but no further progress, i.e.
[Installation not progressing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hC9j.png)

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Press escape and see the terminal output for what is wrong. There is not enough information in this question to answer more meaningfully than that.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: No response when pressing Esc when it hangs... I've been successful in installing Mint 20.3 - as it's based on Ubuntu it probably works for me (software developer).